# Is this a proper Mercurial merge?

Tags: mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

2 main branches:

- stable - used for release and for hotfixes.
- default - used for all other development and all features

Please see revisions 8 and 9 specifically.  I added a 2 separate features in revisions 3 and 4, worked on them separately, merged them into default in revisions 7 and 8.  They are not complete at this time.

My question is, did I do this correctly considering that I am not done with the features and did not close the feature branches?  The connected blue and pink lines at revision 8, along with the blue extension at revision 9 are confusing me.

I'm pretty new to source control, so any explanations are appreciated.

[image: history]

Answer (score 0):

You just have two heads on your tree, which are at revisions 8 and 9 specifically now.  You could run "hg heads" on the command line in that directory to see some textual information about them both.  At this point, you could update to either head, make changes and commit, then update to the other head, make changes and commit, etc.  Also, you could merge your feature branch into the default and then just have one head.  It depends on how long you want to keep your feature branch separate.

More interestingly, are you planning to keep using the "stable" branch? If so, I guess that you could "hg update" to r1, and then merge things from your other branches to there.

Side note: You may be interested in reading about "hg flow", and its branching model.  See for example:

- https://andy.mehalick.com/2011/12/24/an-introduction-to-hgflow
- http://www.carl-berg.se/post/hgflow-git-flow-for-hg

Comment: Before I committed changes to revision 9, I believe that I had a single head at revision 8.  Correct?  As for the stable branch, I plan on merging completed features into default and then closing their respective branches.  At certain points however, I will merge the default into stable, essentially putting out a new release.

Comment: I must first ask, is there an error in your decription?  You state that you worked on features in r3 and r4, then merged them into default.  However, your graph seems to show that you worked on features in r4 and r6 and merged them.  Please clarify.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what you meant.  You worked on two separate paths in feature branches: {r4, r6} and {r3,r5}.  Then you merged those to get r7 and r8, respectively.  Yes, at that time, you probably had only r8 on a head.  But then you went onto your feature-LogTool branch and made a change, which became r9.  That's okay.  When you are ready, you can merge that feature branch into default.

Comment: That is definitely what I did.  That's good to know that it's ok.